# Jquery to Collapse the previous tr and expand the other tr when clicked on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table that contains 2 rows on the click of first row data below `tr` gets expanded. When clicked on second row the data below the second row gets expanded by closing the first row data (collapse). The problem is when I click on the first row back the second row data remains in expanded state. while expanding the first row data as well. could anyone please suggest how to collapse now the second row data?

below is the code snippet:

```
$('tr.header').click(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100, function() {});
  $(this).prevUntil('tr.header').slideUp(100, function() {});
});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Header1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Header2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you insert your html as well?

Comment: sure. i have included now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do, is add a class to every expanded `<tr>` and target them using said class to collapse everything that's expanded regardless of if it's before or after the row you clicked.

Here's a demo that is in no way a complete solution, but it should be enough to give you an idea how this could work.

**EDIT:** As per your request, I changed the code to collapse an expanded section if its header is clicked. The thing I changes is this: When a section is expanded, its header gets an additional class and when a header is clicked, it's section is expanded or collapsed based on wether or not it has the class. Still, this is just a prove of concept and not a full solution, please keep that in mind if you're using this.

```js
$('tr.header').click(function() {
  $('.expanded').slideUp(100, function() {});
  if (!$(this).hasClass('expanded-header')) {
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').addClass('expanded').slideToggle(100, function() {});
    $('.expanded-header').removeClass('expanded-header');
    $(this).addClass('expanded-header');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('expanded-header');
  }
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Header1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="content">
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="content">
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Header2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="content">
    <td>date</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="content">
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

By the way, what you're trying to build here is called an *accordion* and there are [quite](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) [some](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-jquery-accordion/) [solutions](http://demos.inspirationalpixels.com/Accordion-with-HTML-CSS-&-jQuery/) [available](http://www.snyderplace.com/demos/accordion.html) [already](http://www.jqueryrain.com/example/jquery-accordion/) (not to mention [bootstrap has one included](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion)). I don't know if that's any help to you, but maybe you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: thanks for the reply , when i again clcik on Header 1 which is already expanded it should be collapsed. in you case its not :(

Comment: Like I said: This is in no way a complete solution, there are a lot of things that need to be adjusted to your exact needs. But it should be enough to show you how it's done. If you really can't figure out how to achieve the effect you're going for let me know and I'll change my answer. In the meantime take a look at the links I provided in the last paragraph, maybe one of those works for you?

Comment: please change your answer i am unable to figure it out , it would be great help..